# Is there a better way to flatten out a table to take up fewer rows by moving fields in rows with duplicate keys into empty (NULL) fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a table with the recorded date, time and quantity of each item a child was given. My end goal is to pivot on that data, but preserve each individual quantity being given out according to date/time and child.

This is easy to achieve without a pivot, but it still takes up an entire row for each instance. What I want, is to flatten out the results to take up fewer rows. There isn't a huge functional difference, I'm just doing this to take up less real estate in the report that will end up using this data.

Updated to include a query for sample data:

```
DECLARE @Items TABLE (Name VARCHAR(10), Date DATETIME, ItemID INT, Quantity INT)

INSERT INTO @Items VALUES ('Jimmy', '01/23/2017 10:00:00', 1, 2),
                          ('Jimmy', '01/23/2017 12:00:00', 1, 1),
                          ('Jimmy', '01/23/2017 15:00:00', 2, 2),
                          ('Billy', '01/23/2017 09:00:00', 1, 1),
                          ('Billy', '01/23/2017 10:00:00', 2, 3)
```

This is what my starting table looks like:

```
Name    Date                        ItemID  Quantity
Jimmy   2017-01-23 10:00:00.000     1       2
Jimmy   2017-01-23 12:00:00.000     1       1
Jimmy   2017-01-23 15:00:00.000     2       2
Billy   2017-01-23 09:00:00.000     1       1
Billy   2017-01-23 10:00:00.000     2       3
```

I use a join to sum up the quantities for each day, sort the quantities into their own respective columns, and then drop the time:

```
SELECT d.Name, CAST(d.Date AS DATE) AS Date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.ItemID = 1 THEN s.Quantity ELSE NULL END) AS SumBooks,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.ItemID = 2 THEN s.Quantity ELSE NULL END) AS SumPencils,
       MAX(CASE WHEN d.ItemID = 1 THEN d.Quantity ELSE NULL END) AS Books,
       MAX(CASE WHEN d.ItemID = 2 THEN d.Quantity ELSE NULL END) AS Pencils
FROM @Items d
INNER JOIN @Items s ON s.Name = d.Name AND CAST(s.Date AS DATE) = CAST(d.Date AS DATE)
GROUP BY d.Name, d.Date
```

This is the resulting data:

```
Name    Date        SumBooks    SumPencils  Books   Pencils
Billy   2017-01-23  1           3           1       NULL
Billy   2017-01-23  1           3           NULL    3
Jimmy   2017-01-23  3           2           2       NULL
Jimmy   2017-01-23  3           2           1       NULL
Jimmy   2017-01-23  3           2           NULL    2
```

This is the structure I am trying to achieve:

```
Name    Date        SumBooks    SumPencils  Books   Pencils
Billy   2017-01-23  1           3           1       3
Jimmy   2017-01-23  3           2           2       2
Jimmy   2017-01-23  3           2           1       NULL
```

I was able to do this using a cursor to iterate over each row and check a new table for any matches of Date, Name, and Books = NULL. If a match was found, I update that row with the quantity. Else, I insert a new row with the Books quantity and a NULL value in the Pencils field, later to be updated with a Pencils quantity, and so on.

So, I am able to get the results I need, but this check has to be done for every item column. For just a couple items, it isn't a big deal. When there's a dozen or more items and the result has 30+ columns, it ends up being a lot of declared variables and large, repeating IF/ELSE statements.

I'm not sure if this is commonly done, but if it is, I'm lacking the proper verbiage to find out on my own. Thanks in advance for any Suggestions.

Comment: Why do you want two rows for Jimmy?  Why not just aggregate?

Comment: Because I need to know that Jimmy was given two books at one point and then one book at another. I just don't need to know what time. Which is why it's okay for 2 pencils to line up on a row sharing the same date.

Comment: If, as you say, you want this for a report, then let the report crosstab it (it's good at that), and let the database store it properly.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaidm This isn't a simple cross tab or pivot. Also, this query is for the report. If you look at the sample data, you'll see that the it is stored in the database properly.

Answer (score 0):

If we trade the inner join for an [**`outer apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) or a `left join` 
and include those values to the `group by` we can get the results you are looking for based on the test data provided.

```
;with cte as (
select 
     i.Name
   , [Date]     = convert(date,i.[Date])
   , SumBooks   = sum(case when ItemId = 1 then Quantity else null end)
   , SumPencils = sum(case when ItemId = 2 then Quantity else null end)
   , Books      = b.Books
   , Pencils    = max(case when ItemId = 2 then Quantity else null end) 
   , rn         = row_number() over (
                    partition by i.Name, convert(varchar(10),i.[Date],120) 
                    order by b.booksdate
                  )
    from @Items i
      outer apply (
        select Books = Quantity, BooksDate = b.[Date]
          from @Items b
          where b.ItemId = 1
            and b.Name   = i.Name
            and convert(date,b.[Date])=convert(date,i.[Date])
      ) as b
    group by 
        i.Name
      , convert(date,i.[Date])
      , b.Books
      , b.BooksDate
    )
select 
    Name      
  , Date
  , SumBooks
  , SumPencils
  , Books
  , Pencils = Pencils + case when rn > 1 then null else 0 end
  from cte
```

---

alternate `left join` for `b`:

```
left join (
            select Books = Quantity, BooksDate = b.[Date], Name, Date
              from Items b
              where b.ItemId = 1
          ) as b on b.Name = i.Name and convert(date,b.[Date])=convert(date,i.[Date])
```

---

test setup: http://rextester.com/IXHU81911

```
create table Items (
    Name     varchar(64)
  , Date     datetime
  , ItemID   int
  , Quantity int
  );
insert into Items values 
    ('Jimmy','2017-01-23 10:00:00.000',1,2)
  , ('Jimmy','2017-01-23 12:00:00.000',1,1)
  , ('Jimmy','2017-01-23 13:00:00.000',1,1) /* Another 1 Book */
  , ('Jimmy','2017-01-23 15:00:00.000',2,2)
  , ('Billy','2017-01-23 09:00:00.000',1,1)
  , ('Billy','2017-01-23 10:00:00.000',2,3)
  , ('Zim'  ,'2017-01-23 10:00:00.000',2,1) /* No books */
```

query:

```
;with cte as (
select 
     i.Name
   , [Date]     = convert(varchar(10),i.[Date],120)
   , SumBooks   = sum(case when ItemId = 1 then Quantity else null end)
   , SumPencils = sum(case when ItemId = 2 then Quantity else null end)
   , Books      = b.Books
   , Pencils    = max(case when ItemId = 2 then Quantity else null end) 
   , rn         = row_number() over (
                    partition by i.Name, convert(varchar(10),i.[Date],120) 
                    order by b.booksdate
                  )
    from Items i
      outer apply (
        select Books = Quantity, BooksDate = b.[Date]
          from Items b
          where b.ItemId = 1
            and b.Name   = i.Name
            and convert(date,b.[Date])=convert(date,i.[Date])
      ) as b
    group by 
        i.Name
      , convert(varchar(10),i.[Date],120)
      , b.Books
      , b.BooksDate
    )
select 
    Name      
  , Date
  , SumBooks
  , SumPencils
  , Books
  , Pencils = Pencils + case when rn > 1 then null else 0 end
  from cte
```

note: `convert(varchar(10),i.[Date],120)` is used on rextester to override default formatting of `date`. Use `convert(date,i.[Date])` or `cast(i.[Date] as date)` outside of rextester.

results:

```
+-------+------------+----------+------------+-------+---------+
| Name  |    Date    | SumBooks | SumPencils | Books | Pencils |
+-------+------------+----------+------------+-------+---------+
| Billy | 2017-01-23 | 1        |          3 | 1     |       3 |
| Jimmy | 2017-01-23 | 4        |          2 | 1     |       2 | 
| Jimmy | 2017-01-23 | 4        |          2 | 1     |    NULL |
| Jimmy | 2017-01-23 | 4        |          2 | 2     |    NULL |
| Zim   | 2017-01-23 | NULL     |          1 | NULL  |       1 |
+-------+------------+----------+------------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: I updated my question to include a query to create sample data. Your answer is close, but the 2 pencils issued to Jimmy appears in both resulting rows, instead of 2 in one row and NULL in the second.

Comment: None so far. I've been able to clean up and optimize my cursor, but I haven't been able to figure out a better solution.